# i tried to get the value of feet from conversion of meter to feet, but it stay zero(java)

Tags: java

hi im a student i have a problem with my code(java), i know it is so simple for the others but im still learning this language, i cant figure out how can i get the value of feet in my code i use overloading method can someone help me with this? im past my deadline but im still figuring out how to convert meter to feet. (here is the code)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prog10
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int height;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("\n");
        System.out.printf("What is your height?: ");
        height = in.nextInt();

        Conversion convert = new Conversion();
        convert.testConversion(height);
    }
}

class Conversion{
    public void testConversion(int height){
        double meter = 0;
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.printf("the height of a user is: %d cm\n\n", height(height));
        MeterConversion(height);
        FeetConversion(meter);

    }
    public int height(int height){
        System.out.printf("called Height with int argument: %d\n", height);
        return height;
    }
    public double meter(double meter){
        System.out.printf("called Meter with double argument: %.1f\n", meter);
        return meter;
    }
    public double ft(double ft){
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.printf("called Feet with double argument: %.1f\n", ft);
        return ft;
    }
    public void MeterConversion(double height){
        double meter = height * 0.01;
        System.out.printf("The height of a user in meter is: %.1f m\n", meter(meter));
    }
    public void FeetConversion(double meter){
        double ft = meter * 3.281;
        System.out.printf("The height of a user in feet is: %.1f ft\n",ft(ft));
    }
}
```

and here's the output:

C:\Users\Jadee>java prog10

What is your height?: 170

called Height with int argument: 170
the height of a user is: 170 cm

called Meter with double argument: 1.7
The height of a user in meter is: 1.7 m

called Feet with double argument: 0.0
The height of a user in feet is: 0.0 ft

thank you for the help in advance!!!.

Comment: meter is 0, you never changed it in testConversion

Comment: what should i put? should i put the value of meter in voidMeterConversion?

Comment: what are you taking input for height as?

Comment: im trying to get the height as cm to meter to feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prog10
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int height;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.printf("\n");
        System.out.printf("What is your height?: ");
        height = in.nextInt();

        Conversion convert = new Conversion();
        convert.testConversion(height);
    }
}

class Conversion{
    double meter = 0;
    public void testConversion(int height){
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.printf("the height of a user is: %d cm\n\n", height(height));
        MeterConversion(height);
        FeetConversion(meter);

    }
    public int height(int height){
        System.out.printf("called Height with int argument: %d\n", height);
        return height;
    }
    public double meter(double meter){
        System.out.printf("called Meter with double argument: %.1f\n", meter);
        return meter;
    }
    public double ft(double ft){
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.printf("called Feet with double argument: %.1f\n", ft);
        return ft;
    }
    public void MeterConversion(double height){
        meter = height * 0.01;
        System.out.printf("The height of a user in meter is: %.1f m\n", meter(meter));
    }
    public void FeetConversion(double meter){
        double ft = meter * 3.281;
        System.out.printf("The height of a user in feet is: %.1f ft\n",ft(ft));
    }
}
```

Comment: the height is not a fix value, what should i put if i change the zero?

Comment: @JadeeBuenaflor did you get the output?

Comment: the feet conversion is still zero value

Comment: Woah! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! so i just need to remove the double meter in testconversion to get the value of feetconversion, THANK YOU VERY MUCH! now i can pass this to my prof even though its past the deadline.

Answer (score 0):

Is your input always expected in cm?

Do you expect FeetConversion to be called with value in meters?

If so, then you need MeterConversion to return the value in meters as a double

```
public double MeterConversion(double height){...}
```

Then call Feet conversion with the returned value like:

```
double heightInMeters = MeterConversion(height);
FeetConversion(heightInMeters)
```

Such as:

```
public void testConversion(int height){
       // not needed double meter = 0;
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.printf("the height of a user is: %d cm\n\n", height(height));
        
         
        // you need to capture the height in meters so add a return from MeterConversion
        // your existing MeterConversion does not alter the value of height, it stays in cms
        double heightInMeters = MeterConversion(height);
        FeetConversion(heightInMeters);
    }
```

Comment: i need  the feet to be called with value after i convert the meter to feet

Comment: public void testConversion(int height){
       // not needed double meter = 0;
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.printf("the height of a user is: %d cm\n\n", height(height));
        
         
        // you need to capture the height in meters so add a return from MeterConversion
        // your existing MeterConversion does not alter the value of height, it stays in cms
        double heightInMeters = MeterConversion(height);
        FeetConversion(heightInMeters);
    }

Answer (score 0):

meter variable in  MeterConversion() is only a local variable valid only within that method's scope, it does not change the value of meter variable defined in line 21.

if you want to update the value of meter variable (line 21) with the MeterConversion(), you could return that value from the method and assign it to meter variable.

```
    public void testConversion(int height){
    double meter = MeterConversion(height);
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.printf("the height of a user is: %d cm\n\n", height(height));
    MeterConversion(height);
    FeetConversion(meter);

}

public double MeterConversion(double height){
    double meter = height * 0.01;
    System.out.printf("The height of a user in meter is: %.1f m\n", meter(meter));
    return meter;
}
```

Or you could just update the FeetConversion() to convert height into feet

```
    public void FeetConversion(double height){
    double ft = height *0.01* 3.281;
    System.out.printf("The height of a user in feet is: %.1f ft\n",ft(ft));
}
```